# Cloud Solver Options

Tags: solver

For personal work, I am investigating options for commercial solvers.  Prefer a cloud solution so I don't need to invest in higher-compute machines.  I have received pricing for Gurobi Instant Cloud, but would like recommendations from others.

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us the range if problem types you want the solver to address. For instance, if you neef to solve non-convex quadratically-constrained problems, CPLEX (which is available as a could solution) would not handle that.

Comment: If you are not aware Neos-server.org allows you to run (but not abuse) free compute resources and has access to a variety of solvers. If your problem is small enough that might be worthwhile. Depending on your problem it might also be worth it to look into cheap hosting companies which also rent dedicated machines or deploy solvers without hardware license checks in cloud machines as Azure and AWS can be expensive. This means more sys admin duties for you though.

Comment: Range of problems @MarkL.Stone : I am starting independent consulting in supply chain OR.  So mostly LP/MIP/MILP with the occasional QP.  Probably nothing else.

Comment: I am familiar with NEOS , but the size of problems I am scoping with clients, I would not want to send to NEOS.  Thanks for the tip on servers @worldsmithhelper

Comment: If those clients are commercial, using NEOS might be against the [terms of use](https://neos-server.org/neos/termofuse.html) anyway, depending on the individual solver - several of the big names are licensed only for academic non-commercial use.

Comment: Yes @GeoffreyBrent commercial clients.  I'll keep looking into cloud options.  www.datadrivensupplychain.com is my business URL BTW.

Answer (score 2):

You can run [OptaPlanner](https://www.optaplanner.org/) (open source) in the cloud, on OpenShift/AWS/Azure etc.

All of the [quickstarts](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts) contain a docker file. All quickstarts can run in with the JDK docker image, but all the Quarkus quickstarts also support native compilation into a normal linux executable, which is ideal for serverless setups.